# Explain after_initialize if syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

[image]

---

(**update**: typo in image):

```
after_initialize :set_default_role, :if => :new_record?
```

---

So given the above code, I'm curious is there a name for the `:if => :new_record?` syntax?

Why is the `if` statement written as a hash?

Is there a difference if its written as:

```
after_initialize :set_default_role if self.new_record?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the `after_initialize` syntax is **incorrect** in your code.

Instead of:

**`after_initialize: set_default_role`**,

you should call

**`after_initialize :set_default_role`**.

---

That said, `after_initialize` here is a normal method call from the class body (yes, it's possible in Ruby). It's called **once**, when the class is loaded. This method, when invoked, sets a callback (first parameter), to be triggered, in this case, when your Active Record object is instantiated).

In this case `:if` is a key option passed to the `after_initialize` method. It's the same as if you were calling the method like this:

```
after_initialize(:set_default_role, { if: :new_record? })
```

- ***First parameter***: the callback method to invoke.
- ***Second parameter***: Hash Object with some options.

  Just a note: `:if => :new_record?` (*hashrocket notation*) is the same of `if: :new_record?` (*new syntax, JSON-like*).

So, `if` here is just the **key name** of the options Hash Object passed as the second argument of the method invocation (not the conditional `if` keyword).

By the way, you can read more about **Conditional Callbacks** [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#conditional-callbacks).

---

**Why `after_initialize :set_default_role if self.new_record?` won't work?**

That's because this method is called in the class body, with the Class context (`self = User`, not `self = @user`) - once when loaded -, and `new_record?` is an **instance method**. The interpreter would throw a `undefined method 'new_record?'` error.

When you correctly set `if:` key to `:new_record?`, it works like a *pointer*. You're saying: *ok, I'm defining now, in my Class context that, when the time comes (this Active Record object is instantiated), you will look for a method called `set_default_role` in my class **instance**, but only if the **instance** method `new_record?` returns `true`.*

Comment: Thanks. So is `:if` key option **only** valid to specific methods that handles them like `after_initialize`, or is it something that all Ruby methods inherit?

Comment: @resting you're welcome. It's a option for all the [callback methods](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#conditional-callbacks)...